# Cannot reach site via local network to Apache2 server

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I just installed Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and its ip is 192.168.1.107

I have another laptop with ip 192.168.1.103

I failed to send http://192.168.1.107 on laptop's browser because it showed 'This site can’t be reached' back.

On server itself `curl http://localhost` is correct.

I don't know why I cannot access it on another computer in the same local network.

And not sure which conf file I should check for Apache2.

sudo iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source    destination
ACCEPT    tcp  --  anywhere  anywhere    tcp dpt:http
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source    destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target    prot opt source    destination
```

ping 192.168.1.103

```
PING 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
FROM 192.168.1.107 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
FROM 192.168.1.107 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
FROM 192.168.1.107 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

ping 192.168.1.107

```
PING 192.168.1.107 (192.168.1.107) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

arp -a

```
3820TG.Home (192.168.1.103) at <incomplete> on wlx74da386a0cb2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check:

1. On the server, `sudo iptables -L`
2. Ping test: run `ping 192.168.1.107` on your laptop.
3. Another Ping: run `ping 192.168.1.103` on your server.

Follow these steps and append the results to your question.

Update 1:

- Firewall is good
- Can't ping from both sides.

Next Step, Check you router.

If you are using a wireless router, check if there is any setting called `AP Isolation` on the router, disable it.

If there is no such settings, check if you are connecting to a `Guest Network/WIFI`.

Both settings will prevent you from accessing any devices in your local network except the router itself.

Comment: I only know both server and laptop use  wireless network that share from AP. And server can see another computer's HWaddress that use cable. Is that impossible to connect each other when use wireless network?

Comment: @AbbyWu Please tell me your router's brand and model

Comment: I see brand is D-Link

Comment: @AbbyWu The router management IP should be 192.168.1.1, visit that from you browser, and login. Try to find "Enable Wireless
Isolation" via Wireless - Wireless Basics

Comment: Thank you very much!! (I have to wait wireless router's owner wake up...)

Comment: @AbbyWu Also check the Guest Zone setting in the router, (those settings varies by different models). By the way, you said "server can see another computer's HWaddress that use cable", can you ping the IP address associate with that HW address from the server?

Comment: computer with cable can be pinned

Comment: @AbbyWu Then I guess it's that router's problem.

Comment: I misunderstood before. The model is both server and laptop share wireless network from modem, and we cannot configure modem. So it solved by adding an AP to that modem, now they can pinned each other via getting ip from that AP.

Answer (score 2):

Check Firewall Rules, I think your firewall blocks the port 80.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```